# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in -filename- on line -linenumber-

Tags: php, parse-error

**So first, I would just like to inform you that I'm no "genius" or whatever in what I do. It might be a silly syntax error, but please, help me out here. I've been trying for hours. I really appreciate it.**

So the syntax error message was

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in -filename- on line -linenumber-
```

just as in the title. I've marked the line number where the error occurs, so you don't have to worry about that.

```
  $file = fopen("blog.txt", "r");
  $dl = 1;
  $fl = 0;
  $readstr = "";
  while(! feof($file)) {
    $fileline = fgets($file);
    if ($fileline == "") {
      break;
    }
    if(dl == 1) { //heading
      echo "<h3>".$fileline."</h3>";
    }
    else if(dl == 2) { //date
      echo "Uploaded on ".$fileline."<br />";
    }
    else if(dl == 3) { //content
-->   dl = 0;
      echo $fileline;
    }
    fl++;
    dl++;
  }
  fclose($file);
```

I just don't get it. What's wrong in that line? dl = 0. I don't see any syntax error at all near that area.

Comment: variables need `$` affixed to them in PHP otherwise they are treated like constants. SO make sure all of your `$dl` and `$fl` variables are affixed with a `$`, unlike JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are coding in the PHP platform, you need to maintain some convention of variable declaration. Take a deep look in you script, several time you use `dl` and `fl` without the `$` sign, so you need correct them.

Rules for PHP variables: [Online Guide](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)

1. A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the
   variable
2. A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
3. A variable name cannot start with a number
4. A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and
   underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
5. Variable names are case-sensitive ($age and $AGE are two different
   variables)

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'm really sorry that I didn't notice that. I was too accustomed to the other languages I used to program previously. Again, thanks.

Comment: Just read the document carefully and do it. And thanks to `Ohgodwhy`, because he did it for you.

Comment: I understand. That is why I thank everyone who told me this.